# Abstracting a member function with different return types

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have the following C++ classes:

```
class FileIOBase
{
  //regular file operations
  //
  //virtual fstream / ifstream / ofstream getStream();  ???
  //
  bool open(const std::string &path);
  bool isOpen() const;
  void close();
  ...
};

class InputFile : FileIOBase
{
  size_t read(...);
  ifstream getStream();
};

class OutputFile : FileIOBase
{
  size_t write(...);
  ofstream getStream();
};

class InputOutputFile : virtual InputFile, virtual OutputFile
{
  fstream getStream();
};
```

The classes just encapsulate standard in, out, in/out file streams and their operations.

Is there any way to make getStream() part of the interface and move it into FileIOBase?

Comment: If you could, what would you want to do with the result of `FileIOBase::getStream()`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It seems to me that `FileIOBase` is meant to be abstract, and thus it'd probably be pure virtual. (Not that that really helps with implementing it, but would answer your semantic question.)

Comment: nothing! I just want to add it to the interface to force implementation by derived classes. I know I can add them as usual members to the derived classes. and since there are limited numbers of the derived classes it actually makes sense, but I'm just curious!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Not really!  The point of a pure virtual function is that you can call it through a pointer-to-base-class.  What useful things is the OP going to be able to do with a `std::ios` (the common base-class of `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`)?

Comment: @p00ya: The purpose of forcing an implementation is only useful because you can then use them in a polymorphic context.  If you're not going to do that, then there is little point.

Comment: Why though do you want to write an extra layer of encapsulation around something that's already pretty well encapsulated and designed?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good point! I stand corrected :)

Comment: @p00ya: the common base class (`std::ios`) offers [very few member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to make those return values references instead of values. If that is the case, you can have `getStream` in the base class return a `ios&`, then you can have the specific functions return `fstream&`, `ifstream&` and `ofstream&`s because they are covariant with `ios&`:

```
class FileIOBase
{
  ...
  bool open(const std::string &path);
  bool isOpen() const;
  void close();

  virtual ios& getStream() = 0;
  ...
};

class InputFile : FileIOBase
{
  size_t read(...);
  ifstream& getStream();
};

class OutputFile : FileIOBase
{
  size_t write(...);
  ofstream& getStream();
};

class InputOutputFile : virtual InputFile, virtual OutputFile
{
  fstream& getStream();
};
```

Comment: +1 for an answer that solves the problem as stated.  The OP now needs to figure out whether this actually serves them any useful purpose...

Comment: is there any general solution for such situations? using generic programming techniques for example.

Comment: @p00ya00 what situation do you mean?

Comment: when you have the same member function but with different types. What if the return types are not a hierarchy like this case? would it be possible? I have a vague idea of unifying the return types using type erasure. Is it applicable here?

Comment: @p00ya00 that's basically what you're doing here. I don't see any problem with this approach, though I don't know what good it will do to have the member be available in the base class.